# I want to have the content of a pseudo element ::before to be a more complex math result

Tags: html, css

I want to have in the pseudo element ::before of my div a math input that takes the result of a counter and multiplies it with a constant and adds another constant afterwards.

```
.content-button{
    background-color: #FF7E67;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    height: 75%;
}

.content-button::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    opacity: 70%;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    content: counter(section);
}

.content-button:hover::before {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: slide-hover;
    visibility: visible;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

i would like the content of .content-button::before to be:
`section * 10 + 1990`.
Do you have any ideea on how to modify the following line to give my desired result ?
`content: counter(section);`

I tried using a css variable and the function attr(), but it didnt work, i kept searching the web but i couldnt find a solution that does not involve javascript.

Comment: Why not leave logic for JS and representation only for CSS?

Comment: Could you explain the reason for not wanting to use Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done by just CSS.

Set the initial value of the counter to the constant 1990.

Then each time you increment the counter, increment it by 10 not 1. This has the effect of 'multiplying' by 10 each time.

```css
.container {
  counter-reset: section 1990;
}

.content-button {
  background-color: #FF7E67;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  height: 75%;
}

.content-button::before {
  counter-increment: section 10;
  opacity: 70%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  content: counter(section);
}

.content-button:hover::before {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: slide-hover;
  visibility: visible;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-button"></div>
  <div class="content-button"></div>
  <div class="content-button"></div>
  <div class="content-button"></div>
</div>
```